# Inject a service in a model class Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, service, dependency-injection

Suppose I have a service which contains info about the logged user in my Angular application. I have a model called `Sell` that contains a field which is the user `id` who instantiates some `Sell` object. Is there a way to inject (I don't know if "*inject*" is the best word here) the user service inside the model in such way when the constructor is called, Sell takes the user id automatically and assign it to object?

Example:

**user.service.ts**

```
...
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private _id: string = 'some_id';

  get id(): string {
    return this._id;
  }    
}
```

**sell.model.ts**

```
export class Sell {
  userId: string;
  price: number;
  ...

  constructor() {
    // some way to have userService here
    this.userId = this.userService.id;
  }
}
```

**some.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Sell } from '../models/sell.model';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class SomeComponent {

  newSell() {
    let sell = new Sell();
    // with this line, I'd want that the model itself assign user id
    // to its object.
    console.log(sell.userId) // some_id
  }
}
```

Comment: Apart from technical implementation details, you should be aware that this can be considered a violation of the single responsibility principle (the S in SOLID)

Comment: Where injecting it into the component constructor is not

Comment: Thank you @WimOmbelets, I didn't know about SOLID. I'll search for this design principle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you are trying to do is reasonable, the way you are trying to do it is considered a bad practice (big flame war back in the day so not going to get into that)

One of the better ways to do something like that is use Factories to construct your objects.

So your code would look like:

```
// Component needing model
@Component(...)
class SomeComponent {
    constructor(sellFactory: SellFactoryService){
        const sell = sellFactory.getNewSell();
        console.log(sell.userId)

}

/// Sell factory
@Injectable()
class SellFactoryService {
    constructor(private _userService: UserService){ 
    }

    getNewSell(){
       const sell = new Sell();
       sell.userId = this._userService.id;
       return sell;
    }
}

// Your sell class remains dumb (btw Sale would be a much better name for a model)
export class Sell {
  userId: string;
  price: number;
}
```

This way everything remains decoupled and testable.

Comment: Thank you @masimplo. I like this way to solve my problem (even the term 'Factories' is clear to me now).

Comment: In this example, what if `Sell` needed a method, getNextUser() or something that needed to call a method in the service?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't inject service there. Sell class will be just too 'smart' then. I think there are two proper ways to do it:

Inject UserService into SomeComponent (just add it to constructor), and then do

```
let sell = new Sell(this.userService.id);
```

Second way is to create another SellService, which will have UserService injected. It will have method createNewSell(), which will be the same as code snippet above.

Comment: Thank you @mdziob. Yes, Sell class would be just 'smart' and reading the responses and comments, this isn't good for my application. I prefer the second approach, using a service to create a new object .